# FullCalendar After eventLimitClick

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am loading tooltips on my events; however, the tooltips don't seem to work inside of the "eventLimit" popover.

I have tried re-initializing the tooltips on the click event, but the click event occurs **before** whereas I need to re-initialize the tooltips **after**.

Is there an after or some other event I can wire into?

```
// tried this but it doesn't work...
eventLimitClick: function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body', html: true }); // re-init tooltips
  return "popover";
},
```

**Codepen example:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWLKeK?editors=0110

Full-code (for reference):

```
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    defaultDate: '2018-03-07',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
      element
        .attr('title', event.title)
        .attr('data-placement', 'bottom')
        .attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip');
    },
    eventLimit: 2, // allow "more" link when too many events
    eventAfterAllRender: function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body', html: true });
    },
    // tried this but it doesn't work...
    eventLimitClick: function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body', html: true }); // re-init tooltips
      return "popover";
    },
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2018-03-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2018-03-07',
        end: '2018-03-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2018-03-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2018-03-11',
        end: '2018-03-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2018-03-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2018-03-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2018-03-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2018-03-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2018-03-28'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to set the data-toggle attribute in eventRender

```
element.attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
```

then use the generic mecanism in eventAfterAllRender

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(...)
```

rather than just do directly in eventRender

```
$(element).tooltip(...)
```

(More of a question actually, since I am not used to bootstrap.js which seems to be what you are using).

Comment: I like your solution better!  I didn't think of that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to watch for `.fc-popovers` inserted into the `.fc-view` and re-init the tooltips there:

```
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  // add handler to watch items inserted into .fc-view to catch popovers and re-init tooltips
  $('.fc-view').on('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('fc-popover')) {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body', html: true }); // re-init tooltips
    }
  });
},
```

**Codepen example:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVvaLY?editors=0110